# Parallel processing using the AForge.Net library and C#.

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, aforge

My program works as follows:

1. Get new frame from camera.
2. Filter skin color in the frame (i.e. extract skin in the image).
3. Apply motion detection on the result, based on the previous step.

That is, I am trying to detect motion of objects that have skin color. But I want to speed up my program, so I thought about using parallel programming, where I use two threads, one for skin filtering, and one for motion detection, and then do a logical `AND` of the results.

I am using C# and the Aforge.Net library. Can I do what I described using C#? Could you please give me some hints on how to accomplish what I have described? All I have been able to find is `Parallel.For`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do threaded and parallel processing in .NET:

- You either can use a `ThreadPool`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx tells you more about this.
- Maybe you can make use of `TaskFactory.StartNew(...)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx instead.
- Another way would be the BlockingCollection for .NET 4, see BlockingCollection Class in MSDN.
- Also you could write your own ThreadPool-class.